# Change AUTHID of object type in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, authid

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT AUTHID DEFINER IS OBJECT(
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(100)
);
/
```

How to change the AUTHID to CURRENT_USER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run your `CREATE OR REPLACE` statement again with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS OBJECT(
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

**UPDATE**

If you have dependent objects (e.g. a table containing objects of type OBJ_DEPARTMENT), use `ALTER` instead of `CREATE OR REPLACE`:

```
ALTER TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT replace AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS OBJECT   
  (DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Comment: @marionjeff No, it won't. See my updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! seems the answer I'm looking for.